# numbers treated as text giving wrong values in index and sumifs

Tags: excel-formula, worksheet-function

I'm indexing a table that somehow has numbers stored as text, here is a fragment:

`{0\0\0\0\"110"\950\0\0\0\"3485"\0\0\0\"950"\0\0\0\0\0\100}`

When I try to use sumifs for this range, i get wrong values. Is there any way to fix this in formula without changing the data?

This is the exact formula I'm using:

`=SUMIFS(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&"P_"&$C$3&"'!B9:BC100");MATCH($D6;INDIRECT("'"&"P_"&$C$3&"'!BC9:BC100");0););INDIRECT("'"&"P_"&$C$3&"'!B1:BC1");L$1))`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use *SUMIFS* but there's a work-around.
**Something like:**

[image]

So if you have data like above, enter this *array formula*:

`=SUM(IF(INDIRECT("A3:A5")=A$2,VALUE(INDIRECT("B3:B5"))))`

by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
*300* is entered as *Text* but you still get the correct total for all items equal to *A$2* which is `A`.

**Note:** My local separator is `,` (not `;` as in your example) so don't be confused.
Also, above is just an example, I'll leave the actual adaptation of your formula to you. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ranges with numbers stored as text a good way to deal with this is to multiply your cells by 1 as you use them. Example below. You need to leave out the curly braces and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula, which tells excel to individually multiply each number by 1 before summing them (in my example)

[image]

Therefore, you might try the following formula with your data

```
{=SUMIFS(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&"P_"&$C$3&"'!B9:BC100")*1;MATCH($D6;INDIRECT("'"&"P_"&$C$3&"'!BC9:BC100")*1;0););INDIRECT("'"&"P_"&$C$3&"'!B1:BC1");L$1))}
```

Note: I haven't tested this formula, but I did test that this method works with `INDIRECT()`

Comment: You can't do this within SUMIFS because when you apply *1 to a range the result is an array......and SUMIFS can't process arrays